# finding columns with NAs in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and I need to use Python and Pandas to return a dictionary that has 2 values. The first one has the key value "Columns without nans" and the second one has the key "Columns with all nans" The value for the first should be a list of column names that have no nan values. The value for the second should be a list of column names that have all nan values. If no such column exists the list should be empty. How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a column in a dataframe contains any nulls using `df[col].isnull().values.any()` - this will return True if any of the values are null / nan / etc, or you can use `....all()` to find if they all are nan. Wrap this in a loop over cols to append to lists for your dictionary.

```py
all_list = []
none_list = []
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].isnull().values.all():
        all_list.append()
    elif df[col].isnull().values.any() is False:
        none_list.append()
my_dict = {'Columns without nans': none_list, 'Columns with all nans':all_list}
```